# Is there a way to sample a fixed number of points in each polygon of a SpatialPolygon?

Tags: r, spatial

I have a SpatialPolygon of a large grid (~4000 cells, reduced to 2000 for this example).
For this, I want to randomly sample three points for each cell.
So far I have two approaches.
This first one works but is heavy in computations - I even had to split the process in two to make it work.

```
set.seed(123)
pts1 <- spsample(gridcut[1,],n=3,"random")
gc()
for (y in 2:1000) {
  set.seed(y)
  pt <- spsample(gridcut[y,],n=3,"random")
  pts1 <- gUnion(pts1,pt)
}


set.seed(123)
pts2 <- spsample(gridcut[1001,],n=3,"random")
gc()
for (y in 1002:2000) {
  set.seed(y)
  pt <- spsample(gridcut[y,],n=3,"random")
  pts2 <- gUnion(pts2,pt)
}

pts <- gUnion(pts1,pts2)
```

I thought the following snippet could work with the right parameters, but I couldn't figure out how.

```
set.seed(123)
pts2 <- spsample(gridcut,n=3*nrow(gridcut),"stratified")
```

The result of this are randomly distributed points with at least one point per cell (polygon) (so much for the "stratified" option) but not three per cell as I wish.

So far for my particular case.
Adding a simpler reprex - let's say I want three points per region in France:

```
fra <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)
pts <- spsample(fra,n=nrow(fra),"stratified")

set.seed(123)
pts <- spsample(fra[1,],n=3,"random")
for (y in 2:nrow(fra)) {
  set.seed(y)
  pt <- spsample(fra[y,],n=3,"random")
  pts <- gUnion(pts,pt)
}
```

Similarly, this works, but for my case it takes too long and slows my machine down a lot. I am looking for a more elegant solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you restricted to use `sp` or could you use e.g. `sf` or `spatstat`? I think `spsample` will not let you do exactly what you want in a general polygon as the help file says: "The number of points is only guaranteed to equal n when sampling is done in a square box, i.e. (sample.Spatial). Otherwise, the obtained number of points will have expected value n."

Comment: I am not restricted sp. What does the square box refer to: the overall SpatialPolygon or the individual polygons this consists of? If the latter is the case, then this would not work for the France reprex (neither are square boxes), but should actually work for my grid case (SpatialPolygon is Africa, individual polygons are squares).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following quick and dirty solution is not perfect. It pretends your
coordinates are flat when generating the random points. Really you should
project the polygons in `fra` to flat coordinates before proceeding.

```r
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
fra <- raster::getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)
regions <- lapply(slot(fra, "polygons"), function(x) { SpatialPolygons(list(x)) })
windows <- lapply(regions, as.owin)
p <- lapply(windows, runifpoint, n = 3)
co <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(p, coords))
pts <- SpatialPoints(co, CRS(proj4string(fra)))
#> Warning in proj4string(fra): CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
plot(fra)
plot(pts, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is working and I am fine with a certain degree of projection-related imprecision. However, it only works for the first 2000 observations with
```windows <- lapply(cells[1:2000], as.owin)```
For the remainder ```cells[2001:length(cells)]``` I get the error message ´´´Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Gave up after 3000 trials, 0 points accepted´´´.
Any idea where this could come from?

Comment: Answering my previous comment: There was a geometry error that the cleangeo package did not detect. I identified "cells" that were actually lines by filtering through raster::area.